# Are OpenGL Textures more memory efficient than Android Bitmaps?

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

I have a custom map application that deals with many Bitmaps that are 256x256 images (png,jpg). I'm currently using the `View` 2d canvas and bring in all images as RGB_565. Although I'm generally happy with the applications performance,  I have features I'd like to add that will require even more map tiles (Bitmaps). I've been thinking about using opengl but am fairly new to it.

1. Would opengl Textures be more memory efficient than keeping Bitmaps 
   around? I assume you can load a Bitmap into a Texture and then
   dispose of the Bitmap
2. Is it an acceptable practice in opengl to dynamically load many different Textures at runtime?
3. Do you need to cache Textures or does the GPU handle that for you?

**UPDATE:**
I received a [nice detailed answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24691/are-opengl-textures-more-memory-efficient-than-android-bitmaps) to this question on GameStack.

Answer (score 1):

1. Load many Bitmap instance in app may cause OOM sometimes.
2. Load data to texture can be done in native code. It is more efficient than do it in app, just call memcpy, no Bitmap instance needed.
3. you must gen texture and del it explicitly.